# Windows form navigation bar stops working after performing sql command

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I’m building a windows dataGridView (DGV) form app using a table in a sqlserver as data source. The automatically created BindingNavigator works fine when the form is first opened.

The project has a requirement to be able to do a multi-column-sort.  The user can click on the column headers and build a list of cascading “Order By” terms that is appended to a select command.

Once all the desired columns are selected the user clicks a button that performs the sql command. The desired result is then displayed in the DGV.

However, after performing the select the DGV no longer responds to BindingNavigator. It seems the navigator is no longer bound to the DGV.

This is the button click event code:

```
 private void btnMultiSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            if (selectedColumnOrder.Count > 0)
            {
                string sortOrderCSV = string.Join(",", selectedColumnOrder); // Convert List-type to CSV string to use in SQL statement

                sqlConnection.Open();
                string sql = $"SELECT * FROM PendingProjects ORDER BY " + sortOrderCSV + sortOrder;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConnection);

                pendingProjectsDataGridView.DataSource = this.pendingProjectsBindingSource;
                pendingProjectsDataGridView.Update();

                txtBxColSortOrder.Text = displaySortOrderString;

                sqlDataAdapt.Fill(dataTbl_1);  // Fill data from DB-Table into inmemory DataTable-Oject (dataTbl_1) using the SqlDataAdapter (sqlDataAdapt_1)
                pendingProjectsDataGridView.DataSource = dataTbl_1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you use the `Sort()` method of the BindingSource? As of now, you're changing the DataSource of your DGV, twice. Is `pendingProjectsBindingSource` the original source of data? In that case, why are you setting it on a `Click` handler? Then set a new DataSource right after?

Comment: You're not updating the binding source, `pendingProjectsBindingSource.DataSource = dataTbl_1;` and then set your `DataSource` on the `pendingProjectsDataGridView`. In short, you have some routines out of order.

Comment: I have to admit I am very new at C# and windows forms.  My grasp of "binding" and "source" is very hazy and this was the best I result I've managed. I went and did a quick explore of the Sort() method for  the bindingsource and it looks like it could be promising.  Thanks.

Comment: The Sort property of the BindingSource worked perfectly.  Also greatly simplified the code.